Electric dipole
I have a very silly question to ask. If two charges $+q$ and $-q$ same in magnitude form a dipole in a uniform electric field $\vec{E}$, then the force on the $+q$ charge acts in the same direction as of $\vec{E}$ but the force on $-q$ acts in the different way while the $\vec{E}$ acts in the same direction as before. As charge is a scaler quantity thus the direction of force $\vec{F}$ should be on the same way of $\vec{E}$ right? Then why do we consider the force $\vec{F}$ on $-q$  is acting in the different direction and making a torque?

Charge is a scalar and field is a vector. $\vec{E}$ and $-\vec{E}$ are going to have different directions (multiplication of a vector by -1 changes it's direction.)
Since the equation for the electric force on a charge is $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$, when you replace $q$ with $-q$ the direction of the electric force changes. In other words, positive charges feel a force in the direction of the field lines, and negative charges feel a force opposite the field lines.

Thanks it helped

Because that's how  "Electric field"  is defined. Specifically, ' its direction ' is defined as the direction in which force would act upon a positive charge placed at that particular point in space.
Another thing : what originates Electric field at a point for a charge ?
It's all other charges in the space.
So , if we consider only one fixed charge (say , positive) acting on another charge ( $q'$) placed nearby . If the charge $q'$ is postive it would feel a force away from the fixed charge.But if it was negative , the force it would feel would be towards the fixed charge .
Clearly , force on a negative charge is opposite to positive charge under similar conditions.

yes I understood

@MahitoAhito Happy to hear that !

To understand it intuitively I suggest that do not think of an ideal dipole, $\mathbf p$ as having zero length with infinite charges at its ends but rather in your mind visualize it as something having a finite very short length $\mathcal {\mathbf l}$ and finite very large charges $q$, $|\mathbf p|\approx q\mathcal l,$ so that the length ${\mathcal l}$ is insignificant relative to the distance from which you observe it but it also have the same order of scale as the spatial variation of the local field placed it is in.
Now if the dipole is then placed in a field that is constant, then indeed it will experience only torque but no force. On the contrary, if the field varies at the scale of the length of the dipole, short maybe relative to the distance you observe, the dipole will experience a net force that can be expressed as the derivative of the electric field with respect to spatial displacement. Both being vectors, electric field and displacement, the derivative is a tensor which when is multiplied by the dipole moment, a vector, produces a vector that is the net force on the dipole: $\frac{d\mathbf E}{d\mathbf r}\mathbf p=\mathbf F$. If you write $\mathbf p \approx q \mathbf l$, then $\mathbf F \approx  \frac{d\mathbf E}{d\mathbf r}q\mathbf l \approx q\mathbf E(\mathbf {R+l}) - q\mathbf E(\mathbf {R}) ,$ the location of the dipole being between the points $\mathbf {R+l}$ and $\mathbf {R}.$

I'm still in high school so not familiar with tensors..thanks anyway

That is OK, if you understand this then you have just learned what a tensor is...
